# Sed removing after ip

Tags: regex, sed

I have a simple sed question.

I have data like this:

```
boo:moo:127.0.0.1--¹óÖÝÊ¡µçÐÅ
foo:joo:127.0.0.1 ÁÉÄþÊ¡ÉòÑôÊÐ²ÊºçÍø°É
```

How do I make it like this:

```
boo:moo:127.0.0.1
foo:joo:127.0.0.1
```

My sed code

```
sed -e 's/\.[^\.]*$//' test.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider [upvoting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51156293/3832970) if it turned out helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find an IP like substring and remove all after it:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}).*/\1/' # POSIX ERE version
sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}\).*/\1/'  # BRE POSIX version
```

The `([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})` pattern is a simplified IP address regex pattern that matches and captures 1 to 3 digits and then 3 occurrences of a dot and again 1 to 3 digits, and then `.*` matches and consumes the rest of the line. The `\1` placeholder in the replacement pattern inserts the captured value back into the result.

Note that in the BRE POSIX pattern, you have to escape `(` and `)` to make them a capturing group construct and you need to escape `{...}` to make it a range/interval/limiting quantifier (it has lots of names in the regex literature).

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/hxvvuw).

Answer (score 1):

For the given sample, you could capture everything from start of line till last digit in the line

```
$ sed 's/\(.*[0-9]\).*/\1/' ip.txt
boo:moo:127.0.0.1
foo:joo:127.0.0.1

$ grep -o '.*[0-9]' ip.txt
boo:moo:127.0.0.1
foo:joo:127.0.0.1
```

Or, you could delete all non-digit characters at end of line

```
$ sed 's/[^0-9]*$//' ip.txt
boo:moo:127.0.0.1
foo:joo:127.0.0.1
```